# Gridview paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want paging format of grid view like

Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next

Can any one tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: It's not possible with built-in paging; you need to implement custom pager to achieve this.

Comment: You are right but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Gridview1.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NextPreviousFirstLast
Gridview1.PagerSettings.NextPageText = "Next"
Gridview1.PagerSettings.PreviousPageText = "Prev"
```

Comment: No, it don't work; gridview don't support page numbers with Next - Previous buttons.

Comment: @Mayur ah, my bad. How about `NextPreviousFirstLast` and set `PagerSettings.FirstPageText` and `PagerSettings.LastPageText` to string.Empty.

Comment: Hey Bala, what you are doing is that just displaying Next and prev buttons